# How to call external function in chain function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js

This is a case about React and Dapp.

I call web3j to sendTransaction and wait callback by chian fucntion.
While error occur , I can't call the function inside App.

I descibe the situations below codes around error block.

Is it possible to call function handleError?

```
//My code
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
            status: ''
            };
    };
    
    startTrade(){
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from: "0x123....",
            to: "0x456....", 
            value: web3.utils.toWei("2", "ether"),
        }).on('error', (error)=>{
            
            //If write this line,the browser shows directly:
            //Failed to compile
            //src\App.js
            //Line 62:7:  'handleFail' is not defined  no-undef     
            
            //handleError(); 
            
            //If add this. when error occurs,the console shows:
            //App.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleFail')
            
            //this.handleFail();

            //If I call otherHandle,It's work.
            //However I don't have the instance of App to change something...
            //otherHandle();
        }); 
    }
    handleError(){
       console.log("Do something..");
    }
    render(){ return();
    }
}
function otherHandle(){
    console.log("Do something..");
}
```

Comment: yes , it's possible to call a function inside the error block. whats the error you're getting ?

Comment: Hi ~ I had write it into the comment of source code around error block.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  const handleError = (error) => {
    console.log("Do something..", error.message);
 }

  const startTrade = ()=>{
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: "0x0Cb......",
        to: "0x61d63........", 
        value: web3.utils.toWei("2", "ether"),
    }).on('error', (error)=>{
        handleError(error); 
    }); 
}

    // useEffect Function...
    useEffect(() => {
      startTrade();
      // eslint-disable-next-line 
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you..
However my render/return have states to show,
I need have constructor(props) statement to setup this.state ,so I can't use your sample code.

Comment: you can easily use it with the help of hooks and you can also pass props wherever you wants

Comment: Great~
Thank you very much!
Your hint solved my problem perfectly.